# Does anyone know how to create a menu without exiting the page?

Tags: javascript, html

Does anyone know how to create a menu without exiting the page? I want to create a settings menu.

```
<style>
.material-symbols-outlined {
   align: right;
  font-variation-settings:
  'FILL' 0,
  'wght' 400,
  'GRAD' 0,
  'opsz' 48
         }
      </style>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Material+Symbols+Outlined:opsz,wght,FILL,GRAD@20..48,100..700,0..1,-50..200" />

     <a OnClick="open()" <span class="material-symbols-outlined">
engineering
</span></a>
<div class="menu">
<p>Settings</p>
</div>
```

(I know that i should not use onclick but i don't know how to use anything else)

```
<script>
function show(){
div.menu.show=(true)
}
</script>
```

I wanted it to show div but div is always shown

Comment: Icon from google fonts

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because instead of having a specific problem, this question is basically asking how to do something that a tutorial should cover

Comment: For starters, your HTML is broken/invalid.  You'll always want to check and correct that first.  Aside from that, it's not at all clear to me what you're asking.  First you talk about "without exiting the page" and then about "the div is always shown".  What's the exact problem you're asking about?  Can you update the question to include a Stack Snippet with a runnable [mcve] which demonstrates this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Welcome!
you want to use `style="display:none"` on your div
and in the show() function, you want to try this :

```
document.getElementsByClassName('menu')[0].style.display = "block";
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue why your `<div>` is always showing is that you never used any CSS to hide it, and the reason why your `onClick` handler isn't working is because you are calling a function that hasn't been defined.

You can add an event listener to the link and toggle the `.style.display` attribute of the menu.

```js
document.getElementById('openMenu').addEventListener('click', () => {
  const menu = document.getElementById('menu');
  if (menu.style.display === 'block') menu.style.display = 'none';
  else menu.style.display = 'block';
});
```

```css
#menu {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Material+Symbols+Outlined:opsz,wght,FILL,GRAD@20..48,100..700,0..1,-50..200" />

<a id="openMenu">
  <span class="material-symbols-outlined">engineering</span>
</a>
<div id="menu">
  <p>Settings</p>
</div>
```